# How to set JavaScript callback to method of outer (wrapping) object?

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, scope

How to delegate `websocket` attribute `onopen` callback to method of outer object **with outer-object as `this`, not websocket as `this`**? (beaceuse websocket has no function `showAlert`

In other words: **How to call my `MyClient.showConnected` on webscoket connect?**

```
function MyClient() {
    this.websocket = {};
}

MyClient.prototype.showAlert = function( ) {
    alert("Connected!");
};

MyClient.prototype.showConnected = function( evt ) {
    this.showAlert();
};

MyClient.prototype.connect = function( url ) {
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    this.websocket.onopen =  this.showConnected;
}
```

Such way produces `this.showAlert is not a function`. Usage:

```
var client = new MyClient();
client.connect("ws://.......");
```

This is also **not** working:

`this.websocket.onopen =  function(evt) { this.onOpen(evt); };`

Comment: Did you try?
MyClient.prototype.connect = function( url ) {
 var T = this;
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    this.websocket.onopen = function () {
  T.showConnected();
    }
}

Comment: @Flas I suppose that it will work, but just look how dirty is it. I don't want to belive that JS is so shitty that there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyClient() {
    this.websocket = {};
}

MyClient.prototype.showAlert = function( ) {
    alert("Connected!");
};

MyClient.prototype.connect = function( url ) {
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    this.websocket.onopen = this.showAlert.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Just one question, if you use bind, then you lose event original this? (but I like your answer)

Comment: Bind changes only the context (this) for newly created function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function MyClient() {
    this.websocket = {};
}

MyClient.prototype.showAlert = function( ) {
    alert("Connected!");
};

MyClient.prototype.connect = function( url ) {
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    var that = this;
    // that is hidden in connect namespace, some people use _this instead
    this.websocket.onopen = function( evt ) {
        that.showAlert();
    };
}
```

I think your problem is that `onopen` is event. JS always change `this` if it is an event. The best option then is use variable from some namespace and save `this` inside.

Comment: please say me that I don't have to create a variable every time I just want to reference a method.

Comment: Well, if it is an event, then you have to. Events are asynchronous, it loses its content (this)...